# What is a "foreign application" in Android?

Tags: java, android, terminology

At http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html I read:

> A PendingIntent object is a wrapper around an Intent object. The primary purpose of a PendingIntent is to grant permission to a foreign application to use the contained Intent as if it were executed from your app's own process.

I might make some guesses, but what exactly is a *foreign application*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A foreign, or third-party, application is any application other than the one creating the `PendingIntent`.

Comment: why alarm manager and notification is considered as foreign application?

Comment: @Kakaranara: Because the `PendingIntent` objects are used by another process, in your cases a process owned by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Any application whose purpose and service is different to another application is a foreign application to it. for e.g., Viber is foreign application to Whatsapp.

usage of pendentIndent in this android:

> Pending Intent:
>
> It  is a token that you give to a foreign application which allows the foreign application to use your application’s permissions to execute a predefined piece of code. In our android widget example, foreign application is nothing but Home Screen AppWidgetManager and the code to be executed is the Intent that will open messaging app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:"));
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,intent, 0);
```